# IOS Video recording using UIImages arriving at random times

Tags: ios, video, uiimage, recording

I'm developing an iOS app that gets UIImages at random times from an internet connection, and progressively constructs a video file from them as the images come in. I got it working a little, but the fact that the images dont arrive at the same rate all the time is messing up the video.

How do I re-calculate CMTime when each new UIImage arrives so that it adjusts for the varying frame rate of the arriving UIImages, which can arrive anywhere from milliseconds to seconds apart??

Here is what I'm doing so far, some code is not shown, but here is the basic thing

```
.
.
adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
           assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput: videoStream
           sourcePixelBufferAttributes:attributes];

CMTime frameTime=CMTimeMake(1,10); // assumed initial frame rate
.
.


 -(void)addImageToMovie:(UIImage*)img {
     append_ok=FALSE;
     buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[img CGImage] andSize:img.size];
     while (!append_ok) {
        if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData){
            frameTime.value +=1;
            append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.01];
        } else {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.01];
        }
     }
     if(buffer) {
       CVBufferRelease(buffer);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the number of frames. Instead of adding 1, add 10 to frameTime.value.